# Emulator Crashes on click of OK button in "Google play services which some of your applications rely on" dialog

Tags: android, dialog, google-play-services

Im getting " Google play services which some of your applications rely on..." crashes when I press the ok button.[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        try {
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
        }
```

Comment: Google play services work with real phone, they don't work with emulator

Comment: I know this but why does it crash when I click ok? Is there a way to set an action for the ok button?

Comment: It crashes because you are using libraries which are n't supported by the emulator. I think, **but not sure**, that using `try and catch` to catch the exception and the **error** will help you to prevent the crashing.

Comment: Ok Thanks very much, is the purpose of this message to allow users to upgrade Google Play services on a Device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use GooglePlay service on Android emulator you need Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 (API Level >= 17) or higher.

Please refer to this official document http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: I am now getting a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual device that supports some of the Google services.[image]